# Consuming saved object in aspect

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, aspectj

I have a repository class having method like below:

```java
@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("update Form f set f.xmlWithData =:xmlWithData where f.id =:id")
void save(@Param("xmlWithData") String xmlWithData, @Param("id") longid);
```

and an advice after this method like below:

```java
@After("execution(* tr.com.blabla.FormRepository.save(*,*)) && args(xmlWithData,id)")
   public void generateFormData(String xmlWithData, long id) throws Exception {
}
```

My question is:

Is it possible to use the Form f object in my advice method like below:

```java
@After("execution(* tr.com.blabla.FormRepository.save(*,*)) && args(xmlWithData,id)")
public void generateFormData(String xmlWithData, long id) throws Exception{
    if(f.getSomething().equals("blabla") {
        this.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please use indentation for code blocks instead of three backticks. There is online help on formatting, BTW. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. I don't think so, but if you pass Form object as parameter to save method you can do it.